# boost::lambda expression doesn't compile

Tags: c++, boost, boost-lambda

I tried to write a function that calculates a hamming distance between two codewords using the boost lambda library. I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

template<typename Container>
int hammingDistance(Container & a, Container & b) {
  return std::inner_product(
    a.begin(),
    a.end(),
    b.begin(),
    (_1 + _2),
    boost::lambda::if_then_else_return(_1 != _2, 1, 0)
  );
}

int main() {
  boost::array<int, 3> a = {1, 0, 1}, b = {0, 1, 1};
  std::cout << hammingDistance(a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
HammingDistance.cpp: In function ‘int hammingDistance(Container&, Container&)’:
HammingDistance.cpp:15: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘<unnamed>::_1 + <unnamed>::_2’
HammingDistance.cpp:17: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘<unnamed>::_1 != <unnamed>::_2’
/usr/include/c++/4.3/boost/function/function_base.hpp:757: note: candidates are: bool boost::operator!=(boost::detail::function::useless_clear_type*, const boost::function_base&)
/usr/include/c++/4.3/boost/function/function_base.hpp:745: note:                 bool boost::operator!=(const boost::function_base&, boost::detail::function::useless_clear_type*)
```

This is the first time I am playing with boost lambda. Please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot guys! Here is the working code (just for reference):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/if.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using boost::lambda::_1;
using boost::lambda::_2;

template<typename Container>
int hammingDistance(Container & a, Container & b) {
  return std::inner_product(
    a.begin(),
    a.end(),
    b.begin(),
    0,
    (_1 + _2),
    boost::lambda::if_then_else_return(_1 != _2, 1, 0)
  );
}

int main() {
  boost::array<int, 3> a = {1, 0, 1}, b = {0, 1, 1};
  std::cout << hammingDistance(a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You should call `inner_product` as `std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0, ...);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First problem: when using `boost/lambda`, include `<boost/lambda/bind.hpp>` instead of `<boost/bind.hpp>`

Second problem: you need a `using namespace boost::lambda` after the #includes

still doesn't compile though

---

Edit:
Third problem - you need 6 arguments for `std::inner_product`, you're missing an initialization argument. probably add `0` as the forth argument.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong but I think you should have `using namespace boost::lambda;` before your function as the placeholders (_1, _2 etc.) are in that namespace.